# Play Update throwing property not found exception

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3, ebean

I'm trying to update an entity in Play, but when I actually call update I receive a property not defined exception. Here is the model definition:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public long parserId;
```

The update call

```
parserToUpdate.update(parserToUpdate.parserId);
```

And the error

```
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'parserId' of bean class [models.Parser]: No property 'parserId' found
```

Comment: Just some guess: have you tried using `Long` instead of `long` and also using getters and setters instead of public fields?

Comment: Play generates the getters and setters for you. Funny enough though, if you override that with your own, it will in fact update. I've tried Long instead of long, but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I am personally using Ebean and I always provide my own getters and setters and make the fields private.

Comment: I'm now using PropertyUtils to generate them for me and it works fine now.